# Error when trying to edit Content Query Web Part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a CQWP on my publishing site welcome page. When I go to edit the web part, I get a "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred." screen along with  Correlation ID: c6e03d9c-f1be-f0a0-ed33-e826db494520. Does anyone know what is causing this? I've searched all over and can't find a solution.

Edit: I know think I found the error: "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized." I still don't really know what that means or what to do.

Comment: Here's a little over a minute of logs. Click "toggle text wrapping" to make it readable. pastebin.com/jP0HAwy6

Comment: And with the correct correlation id (different then the on in my OP) I get http://pastebin.com/936BFbEb

Still new to SP, learning how to do all this. Posting these comments here in hopes that it will help somebody else at some point

Comment: I believe I found the error, "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized." Not entirely sure what that means

Answer (score 0):

Going through your logs, the error you are getting is

```
   System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.  Parameter name: key   
 at System.Collections.SortedList.IndexOfKey(Object key)    
 at System.Collections.SortedList.ContainsKey(Object key)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.AppendListTypes(SortedList sortedListItems, SPListTemplateCollection listTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.populateListTypeDropDown()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.populateCBQControls()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Ensure that "Title" column for all items in that list are not null**. This is the mostly likely cause for this issue.

Comment: What list exactly though? I'm just trying to edit the web part, I haven't configured it or anything yet. I'm confused what list has null entries

Comment: By default when a content query webpart is added it will look for the Pages Library list, So ensure all the items in the pages library have columns without null.

Comment: It looks like there are two entries on that list, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/gB2xpm8.png

Would the contact column being empty for default be causing this?

Comment: Your Pages library looks fine, Actually the problem seems to be in populating the lists in the site. So if you have custom list templates uploaded to your site, can you run this powershell query to check whether all list templates have a their title field set, (Get-SpWeb "SiteUrl").ListTemplates | ? {$_.Name -eq $null }

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I got when I ran that query... I'm having trouble figuring out if all title fields are set from this http://i.imgur.com/d6PfTAg.png

Comment: ok, this seems to be a known bug with Developer feature which deploys the list "DraftAppsListTemplate" without any title. You can disable this feature with the following power shell command -Disable-SPFeature -Identity e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085 -Url "SiteUrl"

Answer (score 0):

Agree above, after checking the logs, we found there should some column(s) is or are NULL. So doublecheck that and modify if any.

Comment: What list exactly though? I'm just trying to edit the web part, I haven't configured it or anything yet. I'm confused what list has null entries

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the same problem as is mentioned here...

[Connect Explanation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c51ba710-f314-40ad-8387-3cb8a302677d/content-query-webpart-does-not-work-on-the-sharepoint-2013-developer-site-template?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Just run the following and it should fix it...

```
Disable-SPFeature -Identity "e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085" -Url http://sitecollectionurl
```

Hope it helps